# Socket prematurely closed in Bluetooth Chat example

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm stuck in understanding the source code of the ["Bluetooth Chat" example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat). The [BluetoothChatService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.java)  includes a Thread (called *ConnectThread*) that after the creation of a socket (locally named as *mmSocket*), and if all goes well, calls the *connected* method:

```
connected(mmSocket, mDevice);
```

So, the *mmSocket* is passed as parameter. The connected method has the following signature:

```
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device);
```

and includes this line:

```
mConnectThread.cancel(); //mConnetcThread is an instance of ConnectThread
```

The *cancel* method includes this code:

```
mmSocket.close();
```

So the *mmSocket* is closed, and also the socket passed as first parameter of the connected method shuold be closed (since it refers to the same object), and when the next code calls:

```
mConnectedThread = newConnectedThread(socket); // socket should be already closed
```

I think this is wrong, since the socket now is closed, and I can't do anything work on it (like read or write data on `InputStream` or `OutputStream` associated with the socket). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that before cancelling `mConnectThread` in `connected` method it's checked for being not null. At the same time here is a full snippet of call to `connected` starting from line 434:

```
 // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
 synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
     mConnectThread = null;
 }
 // Start the connected thread
 connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
```

it can be seen that `mConnectThread` is set to null before calling `connected`

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake writing in my code `mConnectedThread = null;` instead of `mConnectThread = null;`